# Using lambda expression to access a value in a map using an optional key

Tags: java, lambda

I need to access a value from a map `M<X,Y>` and I have a key of type `Optional<X> key`. I need to use lambda expression such that I can check whether the key is present, if present, access the value using it otherwise, return empty.

I am doing:

```java
return key.ifPresent(xx -> {
    Optional.of(M.getOrDefault(foo(xx), null));
});
```

But it is giving void type provided but required type is Optional. Suggestions into this?

Comment: So you actually have a `Map<Optional<X>, Y>`? Why? Looking for something like `if(map.containsKey(key) && key.isPresent()) { return map.get(key.get());}else{return null;}`?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `Optional.ofNullable` if your map default is `null`?

Comment: Your code is confusing. Try to add your input and expected output.

Comment: Map is of type M<X,Y>. i am having an Optional<X> key, I have to check if the key is not null. If it is not, I will pass it to a function, to convert it to some other form, and use this to access the map. If null, return Optional.empty().

Comment: Seems like `x.map(xx -> M.getOrDefault(foo(xx), null));`  here `.map()` return Optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could b looking for something like:

```
private Optional<Y> findingY( Map<X,Y> M, Optional<X> key) {
    return key.map(M::get);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!